# setx alternative for *nix

Tags: unix, environment-variables

I believe `setx` for windows set environment variable permanently(also after reboot etc). I would also like to know if there is a oneliner like this for unix also (Have done a lot of searching but could not find answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I wanted to set `NPM_TOKEN` and after some trial and error got this oneliner:

```
if [ -z "$NPM_TOKEN" ]; then echo "export NPM_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" >> ~/.profile; source ~/.profile; else echo 'NPM_TOKEN :)'; fi;
```